# Linq query to find date range

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I've got a table that looks like this tracking when a person started a project:

```
PersonId
ProjectId
StartDate
```

I want to use linq (linq-to-entities) to get a result set like this

```
PersonId
ProjectId
StartDate
EndDate
```

Where EndDate is the StartDate of their next Project (when ordered by StartDate) or null if there is no more recent project.

This is what I have done:

```
context.PersonProjects.Select(pp => new {
    pp.PersonId,
    pp.ProjectId,
    pp.StartDate,
    EndDate = context.PersonProjects.Where(pp2 => pp2.PersonId == pp.PersonId && pp2.StartDate > pp.StartDate).OrderBy(pp2 => pp2.StartDate).Select(pp2 => pp2.StartDate).FirstOrDefault()
})
```

Is there a more performant way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more performant (but not as clean-looking) way of doing this would be reading everything into a list ordered on the start date, and then walk the list, and grabbing the start date of the following item, if any:

```
// You need a named class in order to make this work
class PersonProject {
    int PersonId {get;set;}
    int ProjectId {get;set;}
    DateTime StartDate {get;set;}
    DateTime EndDate {get;set;}
}
...
// Run your query, and put the results in a list
var listOfProjects = context
    .PersonProjects
    .OrderBy(pp => pp.StartDate)
    .Select(pp => new PersonProject {
        PersonId = pp.PersonId,
        ProjectId = pp.ProjectId,
        StartDate = pp.StartDate
    }).ToList();
// Now walk through the list, setting the end time to the start of the next item
for (int i = 0 ; i < listOfProjects.Length-1 ; i++) {
    listOfProjects[i].EndDate = listOfProjects[i+1].StartDate;
}
```

The query and the "fix up" portions for this solution are both linear, so the performance would be as good as reading the `PersonProject` table itself.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. This particular table has about 300K rows so I'm not sure about loading them all in memory. Often, I just want an aggregate of these results (e.g. finding the number of people who worked on a project over a period of time), which means this is just a base query for another query so it seems ideal to keep it IQuerya ble

Comment: @Adam If you put the "fix up loop" in a separate method that takes a properly ordered list, you would be able to keep `IQueryable`, and do the fix-up part only when the subset that you want is in memory.

Comment: True, I just can't use "EndDate" to filter the results until after the fix loop. Sometimes I will want to. I may have to do some tests and see how this compares.

Comment: @Adam In this case you may be better off going temporal all the way, and storing the the `EndDate` in the database. This adds a little more maintenance, but it simplifies querying a lot, and also lets you do very performant "as of date" queries straight in the database.